# how to make a header from a table (made of div's) static or fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table made of div's and I want to make the headers of this table static or fixed this is my  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juanpa/9A88t/5/)

```
<div id="my-container">
    <div id="my-table">
        <div id="my-header">
            <div class="my-cell anHead" data-col="1">No</div>
            <div class="my-cell anHead" data-col="2">ID</div>
            <div class="my-cell anHead" data-col="3">ClusterId</div>
            <div class="my-cell anHead" data-col="4">CPU</div>
            <div class="my-cell anHead" data-col="5">End Time</div>
            <div class="my-cell anHead" data-col="6">I/O</div>
            <div class="my-cell anHead" data-col="7">Job Name</div>
            <div class="my-cell anHead" data-col="8">Job Number</div>
            <div class="my-cell anHead" data-col="9">Owner</div>
            <div class="my-cell anHead" data-col="10">Script File</div>
            <div class="my-cell anHead" data-col="11">QName</div>
            <div class="my-cell anHead" data-col="12">Slots</div>
            <div class="my-cell anHead" data-col="13">State</div>
            <div class="my-cell anHead" data-col="14">Task</div>
            <div class="my-cell anHead" data-col="15">Max. Virtual Memory</div>
            <div class="my-cell anHead" data-col="16">Memory</div>
            <div class="my-cell anHead" data-col="17">Start Time</div>
            <div class="my-cell anHead" data-col="18">Submission Time</div>
            <div class="my-cell anHead" data-col="19">Virtual Memory</div>
        </div>
        <div id="my-body">
            <div class="my-row">
                <div class="my-cell">1</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="my-row">
                <div class="my-cell">2</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="my-row">
                <div class="my-cell">3</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="my-row">
                <div class="my-cell">4</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
                <div class="my-cell">blah!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the problem that I have, is that when I make the header or the cell within "position:fixed" the table breaks. any suggestions????

thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like tabular data. If it is then why not use the `table` element itself? Any specific reasons for not using it?

Comment: @Harry has a point, I'd try and use tables for tabular data if it is possible.

Comment: You can update your css like this http://jsfiddle.net/9A88t/2/

Comment: The reason why I'm using div's is because the columns are resizable and sortables and I couldn't do it with regular table :-(

Comment: @juanp_1982: Ok, I get you. Tricky situation but have a look at Example 7 in [this plugin](http://www.tablefixedheader.com/fullpagedemo/) page. You might be interested in it as it allows all operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix position your table header and add a bit of padding to the body so your table head and body don't overlap.

```
#my-header {
    width: 100%;
    display: table-header-group;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
}

body {
    padding-top:54px;
}
```

Is this what you're after? [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9A88t/1/)

Comment: yes, that is what I want, but I just tested on my code and there is another problem. when cells from tbody are wider than cells from thead the table breaks, even with your suggestion